# Getting static object reference from object container and calling its method from within another object

Tags: php, class, methods, scope, static

I have this "container" class to hold static references to various objects (utility, log etc).

For example: "log" object is "set" into static variable $Log in this container class.

Then I can access it by calling:
`Container::get("Log")->debug("something to debug");`

All works ok, but now I want to make such call form within another object's method. There is no error reported, but I don't get anything logged as well.

I assume that calling a static "get" method of a container class returns referenced object and I can call its public methods. Am I assuming wrong? Obviously something is out of scope here, I just don't understand what and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that calling a static "get" method of a container class
>   returns referenced object and I can call its public methods. Am I
>   assuming wrong?

You are right. Objects always pass by reference in PHP. It means you can get an object and use it as you want.

```
$log = Container::get("Log");
$log->someMethod();
```

Comment: My bad. It is working as I assumed. I just had some fatal parse errors and things were failing for different reasons :) Everything is working. Thanks!